# NextJS Rewrite Works Differently for an API than a Page

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, next.js13

We have an architecture where an SSO app posts to a NextJS frontend which then posts data to a Spring Boot backend. To test out NextJS rewrites, we have a Page pages/MyPage.tsx:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const response =  axios.post('/ext-api/login', {
            userName: 'username',
            employeeId: '0123'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

The above code works. However, we want to expose an API, pages/api/OurApi.tsx:

```
       ...
       const response = await axios.post('/ext-api/login', {
            userName: 'username',
            employeeId: '0123'
       });
       ...
```

next.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
       async rewrites() {
           return [
               {
                   source: '/ext-api/:path*',
                   destination: 'http://localhost:8081/backend-api/:path*',
               },
           ]
        }
    };
```

The Page version works, but the Api version returns a 404 error.

```
    AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
```

Why would the rewrite work for the page but not the api?